# Where does the project define the class PermissionsFragmentDirections in CameraXBasic?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-camerax

The following code is from CameraXBasic project at https://github.com/android/camera/tree/master/CameraXBasic

You can see full code at https://github.com/android/camera/blob/master/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/fragments/PermissionsFragment.kt

I search the whole project, and I can't find the declaration of `PermissionsFragmentDirections`. Could you tell me?

**PermissionsFragment.kt**

```
class PermissionsFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if (!hasPermissions()) {
            // Request camera-related permissions
            requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS_REQUIRED, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE)
        } else {
            // If permissions have already been granted, proceed
            Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.fragment_container).navigate(
                    PermissionsFragmentDirections.actionPermissionsToCamera())
        }
    }

    private fun hasPermissions() = PERMISSIONS_REQUIRED.all {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                requireContext(), it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I've not used it yet, but I would assume that class is auto-generated by the Navigation component at build time.

Comment: Thanks!  How can  Navigation componen customize the class name as PermissionsFragmentDirections?  How can  Navigation componen customize the function of  PermissionsFragmentDirections?

Comment: Are you asking how it came up with those names? I'm guessing that's just the standard pattern. In this case, when it processes [the navigation graph](https://github.com/android/camera/blob/master/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/res/navigation/nav_graph.xml), it generates a class for the options to navigate from `PermissionsFragment` to other destinations, and simply appends `Directions` to that name; thus `PermissionsFragmentDirections`. The method name appears to come from [the `<action>`'s ID](https://github.com/android/camera/blob/master/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/res/navigation/nav_graph.xml#L28)

Comment: You'll notice that it's similar for `CameraFragment`'s navigations [here](https://github.com/android/camera/blob/master/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/fragments/CameraFragment.kt#L149) and [here](https://github.com/android/camera/blob/master/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/fragments/CameraFragment.kt#L386), and [its entry in the navigation graph](https://github.com/android/camera/blob/master/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/res/navigation/nav_graph.xml#L36).

Comment: Just FYI, apparently it's specifically [the Safe Args plugin](https://github.com/android/camera/blob/master/CameraXBasic/app/build.gradle#L21) that generates those `Directions` classes. I don't know why I didn't just peruse the dev pages earlier, but here are some links to relevant info: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args, https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-migrate#pass_arguments_safely. It seems like I guessed correctly, for the most part.